# Pass member template function with unknown signature and possibly overloaded to template

Tags: templates, c++11, signature, pointer-to-member

I'm writing a template to extract the return type of a member function with a specific signature. I need this in order to create a type_trait that verifies some constraints on this type, so that I can `enable_if` certain optimizations if I can use them. At the moment I have this code, which seems to work fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    const double & foo(size_t i) const;
    const int & foo(size_t i);
};

struct B {
    const double & foo(size_t i);
    size_t bar() const;
};

struct C {
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_cv_ref { using type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type; };

template <typename Z> auto fooRetType(Z* z) ->
    // Here I select the function name and its arguments
    typename remove_cv_ref<decltype(z->foo(std::declval<size_t>()))>::type;

// Fallback, returns whatever type
template <typename Z> auto fooRetType(...) -> int;

template <typename M>
// Here I can select between const and non-const versions
// (currently const)
using K = decltype(fooRetType<const M>(0)); 

int main() {
    // Here only A has a foo(size_t) const, so it's the only
    // one that matches.
    std::cout << "Is double? " << std::is_same<double, K<A>>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << "Is double? " << std::is_same<double, K<B>>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << "Is double? " << std::is_same<double, K<C>>::value << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

While I can easily select between `const` and non-`const` versions of the method by changing the type I pass to `fooRetType`, I'd love to be able to also pass to it the name of the functions and its argument signature.

Is it possible to do something like this (bonus if it's without macros), or am I stuck with creating a pair of functions for every signature I want to check?

Comment: Is there a reason for `decltype(testA)`? Why not just `is_same<double, K<A>>::value`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh yeah, right. That part is not really important, just a showcase on how it works =)

Answer (score 1):

```c++
namespace detail{
    template<typename T>
    using identity = T;

    template<typename...>
    struct voider { using type = void; };
    template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

    template<typename Sig, template<typename> class M = identity, typename = void>
    struct has_foo : std::false_type {};

    template<typename C, template<typename> class M, typename... Args>
    struct has_foo<C(Args...), M, void_t<decltype(std::declval<M<C>&>().foo(std::declval<Args>()...))>> : std::true_type {};
}

template<typename Sig>
using has_foo = detail::has_foo<Sig>;

template<typename Sig>
using has_const_foo = detail::has_foo<Sig, std::add_const_t>;

int main() {
    static_assert(has_const_foo<A(size_t)>{});
    static_assert(has_foo<B(size_t)>{});
    static_assert(!has_foo<C(size_t)>{});
}
```

Comment: Looks really nice, thanks! Would it be possible to also add `foo` or `&A::foo` as a parameter, or is that impossible?

Comment: @Svalorzen No, that's not possible. You'd get a compilation error if `A` does not have a `foo` (because the expression `&A::foo` itself would be ill-formed). [This is the closest I've gotten](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb8f98a004b30991). Maybe someone can figure it out.